# Batch file: for parameters

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos

I am having trouble understanding what does following windows batch file do, can somebody explain:

```
for /f %%i in ("%0") do set curpath=%%~dpi
cd /d %curpath% 
/*Some other code...*/
cd /d %curpath%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%0` is the full path to the .bat file itself (if run from another directory) and `~dpi` is a modifier to extract the drive and directory from a path omitting the file name, so this snippet sets the current drive & directory to the one in which the batch file lives.

I can't see the reason for using a `FOR`, `%~dp0` does the same thing in one go.

Comment: Not only does %~dp0 do the same thing in one go, it is also more correct. The FOR version only looks at the first "word" if the path contains any space characters. Also, %0 is not the full path, but just the first word that was typed on the command line (usually the name of the batch file). It may contain a relative path.